# How to tell Visual Studio to build more projects at the same time?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a solution/project that has many projects. Currently, when I build the whole solution, 8 projects, at a time, will build together. In other words, 8 projects will start building, and once one is done, another will pick up and build along with the other (currently) building.. etc.

Are there any settings for this? How can I tell VS to build more (maybe all) projects at the same time?

Comment: they do not have any dependencies on each other? if not then try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/building-multiple-projects-in-parallel-with-msbuild

Comment: @PawełŁukasik They do have dependencies between each other